# JavaFX external Drag & Drop distinguish copy and move

Tags: javafx

I have a JavaFX application that implements drag & drop behavior to and from external applications working with one exception.

If I drag a file, say from desktop on Windows, into my application while holding control-key down (copy operation instead of move), I do not know how to detect that it is indeed a copy operation and not move operation.

I can check the control key when dragging *out* from the application, but this does not seem to work vice versa.

Any ideas?

Comment: doesn't the drag event have that information?

Comment: Oh, DragEvent does indeed have a getAcceptedTransferMode() which solved my problem. Thanks for pushing me to right direction! I was thinking too much in mouse events...

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it so if other have an issue they will know how you resolved it

Answer (score 1):

`DragEvent` has a `getAcceptedTransferMode()`-method that does the trick.